# Azure B2C in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal, maui

```
    <application android:label="ADB2CAuthorization">
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msal59206468-8451-4503-b081-79b09b295d1a" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Addition of the above pasted code to the AndroidManifest.xml file causes the application to produce the following error.

```
Error XA0134: The application does not have the 'android:debuggable' attribute set in the AndroidManifest.xml.
This is required in order for Fast Deployment to work. This is normally enabled by default by 
the Xamarin.Android build system for Debug builds. Please check that you to not have this attribute
set on the 'application' element in your 'AndroidManifest.xml'.
If you have a class that derives from 'Android.App.Application' and are using the '[Application]' make sure the 
'Debuggable' property is not set at all as it will override the value for debug builds.         0
```

Addition of the debuggable property makes the application fail to deploy.

Anyone who successfully integrated MSAL into his/her MAUI app for android please help

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msal59206468-8451-4503-b081-79b09b295d1a" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MauiAppBasic.Platforms.Android.Resources.MsalActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msal59206468-8451-4503-b081-79b09b295d1a" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Then create a C# class inside the Android project
**MsalActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace MedbaseApplication.Platforms.Android
{
    [Activity(Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
        DataHost = "auth",
        DataScheme = "msalxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx")]
    public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
    {
    }
}
```

For more follow the link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/authentication-in-dotnet-maui-apps-msal/
And this Xamarin guide might assist too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations